# How to properly change a Flutter app name for iOS

Tags: flutter

I've followed the instructions detailed on nearly every website:

1. Edit `ios/Runner/Info.plist`
2. Find the `CFBundleName` key and change its value to the app name.
3. Run `flutter clean && dart pub get`
4. Debug/build

Whatever I do, the app is still called "MyApp Mobile" instead of just "MyApp". Android has no problem with the name change. Why isn't this working?

(Flutter 3.0.5, Dart 2.17.6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it turns out there are *two* values one needs to change in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
```

Most of the references out there fail to mention that.

Comment: It's there on the official docs (how to property set e.g. dusplay name): https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Answer (score 1):

You have to change two values to have the name properly displayed on your ios Emulator.
In ios/Runner/Info.plist change the "MyApp"

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
```